# Riemann Zeta continued fraction approximants

Tags: algorithms, riemann-zeta, continued-fractions, polylogarithm

In the paper [Continued-Fraction Expansions for the Riemann Zeta Function and Polylogarithms by Djurdje Cvijovic and Jacek Klinowski](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1997-125-09/S0002-9939-97-04102-6/S0002-9939-97-04102-6.pdf), there is a claim that I cannot reproduce. In the abstract they claim "For example, the 11th approximants for all ζ(n), n ≥ 2, give values with an error of less than 10^(−9)." When I implement the algorithms they describe, however, the 11th approximant for ζ(2) is 1.62328... which has an error of more than 0.02. I have carefully checked that my implementation is correct. I was wondering if anyone has been able to verify this problem?

Comment: The least they could have done was to give an explicit example, say for $\zeta(5)$, so one can check if there was a typo in their algorithms.